# How to remove file from mysql database

Tags: mysql, database

I'm wanting to remove a file from a mysql database. I looked around tried a few things but I can't figure it out.

[image: Mysql file i want to remove]

My question is how do I remove the "New" file its not being used?

Comment: It's not a file, or a table. It's just a button to create a new one.

Comment: ok thank you  just wanted to see if i can remove it or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that's just a button phpmyadmin adds so that you easily can add a new table or database, it isn't actually there if you access mysql via commandline.

Comment: thanks for reply its not in the .sql file when i export but when i import its there i remember awhile back tho i was going to add a new table but cant remember there is nothing inside the file it just there doing nothing but collecting dust...so to speak